# How to make tabs occupy full width and height of header area in tabpane in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a tabpane whose tabs are on its left side. They occupy only width as same as its font size, while rest of the portion of header is empty. Also the space before the first tab makes the tabpane more ugly !. I did found a solution but it   more space which adds another menu in tabbed pane. Currently I am using this one:

```
    pane.applyCss();
    pane.layout();
    pane.requestLayout();
    //tabs are on the left side
    tabPane.setTabMinWidth(tabPane.getHeight()/3-17);
    tabPane.setTabMaxWidth(tabPane.getHeight()/3-17);
```

But it still leaves some space at the end(not the beginning). If change it to 18, then another menu is added to header-area.

Thanks!